# Getting application context into fragment, ViewPager

Tags: android, android-context

I'm writing a simple app with swipe view using `viewpager` and `fullscreen` fragments. In one of fragments I want to check internet connection status before displaying some data but I can't get the application context. I've found a lot of topics on this issue, but none of solutions works for me. I am using `getApplication()` within fragment but even though I get error `"Unreacheable statement"`.

Any advice?

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //setting fragment view pager
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new   PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

First fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CurrentWeatherFragment extends Fragment {

//flaga dla statusu polaczenia z internetem
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

//klasa detektora połączenia
ConnectionDetector cd;


@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentweather, container, false);
    return v;

    //tworzenie klasy detektora
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    //sprawdzenie czy jest polaczenie z internetem
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    }
}
```

Pager Adapter class

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0){
        case 0:
            return new CurrentWeatherFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ForecastFragment();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `CurrentWeatherFragment`'s `onCreateView` you inflate the `View` then instantly return it.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentweather, container, false);
    return v;

    //tworzenie klasy detektora
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    //sprawdzenie czy jest polaczenie z internetem
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
}
```

Move the `return v;` to the end of the method:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentweather, container, false);

    //tworzenie klasy detektora
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    //sprawdzenie czy jest polaczenie z internetem
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

    return v;
}
```

Comment: It worked! This was solution that I was looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lifecycle problem. Make that call in `onAttach(Activity)` instead of in `onCreateView()`

Comment: well, there is no error now, should I continue code within `onAttach()` to check connection? Iam still learning fragments